# How to write a JSON file to a specific location using the Media Store API in Android

Tags: android, mediastore

Having invoked a directory selector on Android with:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
intent.addFlags(
     Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
             or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
             or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
             or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
)

activity?.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FOLDER_PERMISSION)
```

And having obtained the URI of said route in `onActivityResult()`, being the URI of the form (example in case of having chosen a folder named *backup* in the root of the external storage):

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:backup`

At this point, how do you write a file to that location? After researching various answers on how to write files using the Media Store API, all the examples I've seen use constants to refer to already existing media directories, but in my case I want to create a new document (which is a JSON file) in the directory chosen by the user.

Comment: "how do you write a file to that location?" -- wrap that `Uri` using `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`. Use ``createFile()` on that `DocumentFile` to create a `DocumentFile` representing the file. Use `getUri()` on the file's `DocumentFile` to get a `Uri` pointing to that file that you wish to create. Call `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, providing that `Uri`, to get an `OutputStream` on that location. Then, write your content to that `OutputStream`, `flush()` and `close()` the stream, and you should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare for pointing me in the right direction:

```kotlin
var outputStream: OutputStream? = null

try {
    val uri = Uri.parse(path)
    val document = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri)
    val file = document?.createFile(mimeType, filename)
        ?: throw Exception("Created file is null, cannot continue")
    val fileUri = file.uri

    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(fileUri)

    val bytes = content.toByteArray()
    outputStream?.write(bytes)
    outputStream?.flush()

} catch (e: Exception) {
    // Handle error
} finally {
    outputStream?.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not use the MediaStore to save a file if you obtained an uri using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to get permission for a folder.

Just continue to use Storage Access Framework and implement DocumentFile.createFile().

Pretty basic exercise for learning SAF.

If you want to use the MediaStore to save a file then you do not have the user to select a folder first.